# Install Omnipay GlobalIris payment gateway for Expresso Store

Tags: expressionengine, omnipay

I've pulled the Omnipay GlobalIris payment gateway from the repo shown below and added the code to the third_party/store/vendor/omnipay directory in Expression Engine - where there are already a number of other Omnipay gateways installed.

https://github.com/maclof/omnipay-global-iris

I can't figure out how to go about completing the installation and adding the GlobalIris gateway to the others - do I need to edit a composer.json file somewhere and then run composer?

Comment: Editing a composer. json file and then running composer is the normal process for composer apps but it might be different for Expression Engine. Perhaps ask on the EE support forums.

Comment: Thanks - EE forums sounds a good idea.